# R - Recursively find number of sub lists

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists (let’s call the main/parent list A). The number of sub-lists in list A varies: A[[1]] could have 1 sub-list, whereas A[[14344]] could have 6 sub-lists. I need to find the number of sub-lists for each element of A. The goal is to find or write a function that will return `A[1] = 1` and `A[14344] = 6`.

Using `length` or `lengths` alone doesn't work for me -- see the example below:

```
A[1] # element 1 of list A contains 1 sub-list with 5 values
   [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    3
[3,]    4
[4,]    5
[5,]    6


A[2] # element 2 of list A contains 5 sub-lists with 5,2,2,3,4 values (respectively)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 15 16

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 18 19

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 23 24 25

[[1]][[5]]
[1] 30 31 32 33

# using lengths() returns the entire list for A[1] and the length of each element in list 2 
lengths(A[[1]]))
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    3
[3,]    4
[4,]    5
[5,]    6

lengths(A[[2]])
[1] 5 2 2 3 4

# using length returns just 1 for both 
length(A[1])
[1] 1
length(A[2])
[1] 1

# structure of sub-list 1
str(A[1])
List of 1
$ : int [1:5, 1] 2 3 4 5 6

# structure of sub-list 2
str(A[2])
List of 1
$ :List of 5
  ..$ : int [1:5] 2 3 4 5 6
  ..$ : int [1:2] 15 16
  ..$ : int [1:2] 18 19
  ..$ : int [1:3] 23 24 25
  ..$ : int [1:4] 30 31 32 33
```

For the example above, I need something that gives `A[1] = 1` and `A[2] = 5`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `lengths`

```
lengths(A)
```

For example, for this list

```
A <- list(a = 1, b = c(1, 2, 34))
out <- lengths(A)
out
#a b 
#1 3
```

So `out[[1]]` returns 1 and `out[[2]]` returns 3.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define "test" as a list, which has a list at index "a", which in turn contains lists "b" and "c". "test" will also have an index "d", which is the mtcars data set:

```
test <- list(a = list(b = list(), c = list()), d = mtcars)

str(test)

List of 2
 $ a:List of 2
  ..$ b: list()
  ..$ c: list()
 $ d:'data.frame':  32 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
  ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
  ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
  ..$ wt  : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
  ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
  ..$ vs  : num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ am  : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

The function you've described should count the objects indexed at "a", "b", and "c" as lists. The data frame at index "d" is also technically a list, but we can use a check to exclude that.

Our function should therefore return a value of 3.

```
countLists <- function(x, count = 0) {

  sapply(x, function(y) {
    if (is.list(y) && !is.data.frame(y)) {
      count <<- countLists(y, count + 1)
    }
  })
  return(count)
}

countLists(test)

3
```